Can I boot up from a USB thumb drive if I have an installed NVMe SSD drive?
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 with Bookworm installed on an NVMe SSD and it boots up like a champ.  I would like to try to boot up to Android so I used the Imager and installed the Emteria Android image to a USB thumb drive.  I changed the boot order to: BOOT_ORDER=0xf416
I have no SD card installed.  When I reboot it never goes to the USB drive, it just boots from SSD and right into Bookworm. According to the BOOT_ORDER shouldn't it first try to boot from USB, then SD, then SSD?  Did I miss a setting somewhere?

boot order is ealuated from right to left. Your value always puts nvme first. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#boot_order-fields
